# Não iniciar o calendário (eventCalendar) com proximos eventos

Tags: javascript, calendar

Gostaria de começar o calendário mostrando os eventos do mês atual e não os próximos eventos.

```
<link href="admin/coisasDoSite/calendario/EventCalendar/css/eventCalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
<link href="admin/coisasDoSite/calendario/EventCalendar/css/eventCalendar_theme_responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>


<script src="admin/coisasDoSite/calendario/jquery/jquery_1.9.1_jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="admin/coisasDoSite/calendario/EventCalendar/js/moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="admin/coisasDoSite/calendario/EventCalendar/js/jquery.eventCalendar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="calendario"></div>
<script>
   window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementsByClassName("eventCalendar-monthTitle").click();
}
    $(function () {
        $('#calendario').eventCalendar({
            eventsjson: 'calendario.php',
            jsonDateFormat: 'human',
            dateFormat: 'dddd D/MM/YYYY',
            eventsLimit: 12,
            locales: {
                locale: "pt",
                monthNames: ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julio", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"],
                dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sabado'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
                txt_noEvents: "Não há eventos para este periodo",
                txt_SpecificEvents_prev: "",
                txt_SpecificEvents_after: "eventos:",
                txt_next: "siguiente",
                txt_prev: "anterior",
                txt_NextEvents: "Próximos Eventos:",
                txt_GoToEventUrl: "Ver",
                "moment": {
                    "months": ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julio", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"],
                    "weekdays": ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sabado'],
                    "weekdaysShort": ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
                    "weekdaysMin": ["Do", "SE", "TE", "QU", "QUI", "SE", "SA"]
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

["Documentação" da biblioteca](http://www.vissit.com/projects/eventCalendar/)

Comment: Acredito que se houver algum evento marcado ainda no mês atual deva iniciar o calendário neste mês. Seu calendário ainda tem algum evento a ser realizado neste mês?

Comment: ele inicia no mes porem pega todos os meses para frente

Comment: Na pagina demo não vi isso que vc está dizendo. Você pode mostrar o link da sua página? Mas o melhor seria vc postar o codigo na pergunta

Comment: http://associacaoeua.com.br/

Comment: Então, a filosofia é mostrar próximos eventos. Se houvesse eventos no mês seriam mostrados. Se houver somente eventos em dezembro são esses que serão mostrados.

Comment: Correto. Gostaria de começar só com o mês atual

Comment: Você já tentou colocar EventsLimit: 0 se no mês não houver eventos? Se der resultado a preocupação é na virada do mes setar isso de novo

Comment: Essa pagina é em PHP?

Comment: essa pagina é php.

Comment: vou ter q sair agora, logo mais vou instalar isso em uma pagina php e fazer uns testes no meu servidor.

Comment: Sem tutorial de instalação fica complicado! Não entendi como incluir ou retirar eventos. De qq forma acho q o q vc quer é impossível.